# Self-executing code not working?

Tags: javascript

I recently put my code in a self-executing block.

Now when I try to run the code it returns an error of file VM6963:18 in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var input = document.getElementById("find");

    (function placeFinder(input) {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            if (!place.hasOwnProperty("formatted_address")) {
                input.setAttribute("title", input.value);

                return null;
            }

            input.setAttribute("title", place.formatted_address);
        });
    })(input);
})();
```

Comment: How does the version without the IIFE look like (the one that worked)?

Comment: It means there is no element with id 'find'.

Comment: Why do you have *two* blocks of immediately-invoked functions?

Comment: The thing is, I *do* have an element with id `find`. :/

Comment: Is this JS called before or after #find exists in the DOM? Show us the full HTML.

Comment: @Reeno Yes, it's called in the header tags of the HTML.

Comment: @KidDiamond: Place this JS *below* the element. The element has to exist before the JS is called

Comment: By the time this code runs, there is **no** element with id `find` yet. DOM tree is not yet rendered.